# Chi2cdf upper python

Tags: python, matlab, chi-squared, cdf

So I,m translating Matlab to python code and came across this line

```
Pv = chi2cdf(Devk,Md,'upper');
```

Where Devk is a 3D matrix and Md is df=10.

I was looking for the equivalent in Python. 
I've found this:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2
Pv = chi2.cdf(Devk,Md)
```

However, this does not give similar results, I guess because of the "upper" argument Matlab has. Does anyone has an idea of how to implement this in Python?

Someone asked to make some toy data to show the problem:

Matlab:

```
Devk = [1,2,3,4,5]
Md = 10
Pv = chi2cdf(Devk,Md,'upper')
Pv =
0.9998    0.9963    0.9814    0.9473    0.8912
```

Python:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2
Devk = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
Md = 10
Pv = chi2.cdf(Devk,Md)
Pv
Out[125]: array([0.00017212, 0.00365985, 0.01857594, 0.05265302, 0.10882198])
```

Comment: I would add the MATLAB and the Python outputs for toy `Devk` and `Md` inputs to your question.

Comment: Well Devk is really big matrix of 500x8x8 in which the numbers can vary a lot. But is similar for both Matlab and Python. And Md is just the number 10 for both.

Comment: OK, but can you reproduce the *unexpected behavior* with toy data?

Comment: Ah, noted and added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following holds:

```
chi2cdf(..., 'upper') == (1 .- chi2cdf(...))
```

So, in your Python code it is likely that you have to do:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2

Pv = 1 - chi2.cdf(Devk, Md)
```

## EDIT:

Even better to use:

```
Pv = chi2.sf(Devk, Md)
```

because, according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2.html), the survival function `sf()` (also defined as `1 - cdf()`), is sometimes more accurate.